# Exporting the results of code evaluation in org-babel by default

Tags: org-export, org-babel

I have these settings for evaluating emacs lisp code in babel:

```
ELISP> org-babel-default-header-args:emacs-lisp
((:eval . "never-export")
 (:exports . "both")
 (:hlines . "yes")
 (:colnames . "no"))
```

Here is an example document.

```
#+TITLE: Title

Here is some advanced math.

#+BEGIN_SRC elisp
 (+ 1 1)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 2

And here is some more.

#+BEGIN_SRC elisp
 (+ 2 2)
#+END_SRC
```

When I export this document to pdf, the results are not exported. Why not? `org-version` holds 8.2.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `:eval . "never-export"` means " The code block will not be evaluated during export but may still be called interactively". You can either change this to "yes", or leave it the way it is and do `M-x org-bable-execute-buffer` before exporting.

**Edit:**
It looks like the issue was not unevaluated code blocks as I assumed in the original answer. Rather, you should use the official identifier `emacs-lisp` rather than `elisp`, i.e.,

```
#+TITLE: Title

Here is some advanced math.

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
 (+ 1 1)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 2

And here is some more.

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
 (+ 2 2)
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: But what there is already a result for the first code block. I want to export that without having to execute the code block for the second one.

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess you just need to set `org-babel-default-header-args:elisp`, or use `#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp` as the code block delimiter. I've updated the answer.